TTL232 read with a FT232BL USB converter
Gentlemen,
I'm trying to read a "TTL232" source from a Coulombmeter (TF03K, "Baiway TF03H v35" on the board) that has the following pin on the board: "RXD", "TXD", "GND" and "VCC", where I soldered 4 Dupont Cables.
My Voltmeter reads +5V on the VCC-GND and a floating voltage on the TXD-GND pair.
I found two different PDF of the communication protocol, one that stated 9600bps (and "Note: the VCC and GND must connect to external power. The interface is not RS-232. So it can't be connected directly. It must be TTL level.") and another that stated 19200bps (and the notes "The serial port of this product is TTL232, not RS232, and can not be connected with the RS232 of the computer host!
At present, the communication output of this product is only valid for TXD, RXD has no receiving function, so it can be disconnected.
VCC(V) is an isolated power supply of 5V. If the connected device has a 3V or 5V power supply, it can be disconnected.").
Both have the same protocol:

So I connected a FT232BL, GND-GND and TXD-RXD to the Coulombmeter, because of the only person I found out connecting to it (https://github.com/edillmann/tf03mqtt), then I connected the FT232BL to a RPi, and tried to set both 9600bps and 19200bps, but no data seems to be read from that device with a simple Python script as the one here below:
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port= '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate= 19200,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout= 1
)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr, "Please wait" )
print('ttyUSB0 is now Open!')
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

while True:
    data = ser.read(16)
    print(data)

Because it only returns me a list of

b''
b''
b''

What am I missing here? How can I read from that device? Thanks in advance!

Check the TXD signal with an oscilloscope.

The "TTL232" signal will be inverted compared to "proper" RS-232 signal levels - that's why the instructions say it cannot be connected to a normal computer RS-232 port.
You will need to add an RS-232 line driver between that device and an RS-232 serial port, or you may be able to find a USB<->TTL-level serial adaptor that can interface directly with your device.

But the used FT232BL is a "TTL232" thing already. Even if it were an RS-232 level receiver, it would receive at least garbage.
